# How to prevent gradle build from executing test task

Tags: gradle

I know that I can use the -x test option to prevent the test task from getting called. I also have something like this in my gradle script to prevent tests from being executed in certain cases:

```
plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).whenPluginAdded {
    test {
        doFirst {
            if (env.equals('prod')) {
                throw new StopExecutionException("DON'T RUN TESTS IN PROD!!!!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but is there a way to configure the java plugin to removed the dependency between build -> test?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

build depends on test via check. You probably don't want to remove the dependency on check as it may do other things, so you could try:

`check.dependsOn.remove(test)`

Do you mind if I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the response! We have several projects that use dbunit to help support our test cases. Currently these projects are built with ant (ant build does not run our tests, you have to explicitly call test). Each env has it's own database schema. Developers will run these tests utilizing their individual schemas... same thing for our continuous integration env. For our staging and production env we do not run these tests. I believe it is bad practice to run tests like this against prod databases, hence the reason for wanting to change the default behavior of the java plugin.

Comment: Hi! I agree you probably don't want to run tests in production, but does this mean you are actually compiling/building your application in production, rather than building elsewhere and deploying it to your prod environment? Just interested in how other people do things :)

Comment: Tried that this morning and no luck, the tests still run. I'm the same way.... like to know how other people do things. Yes, we do compile our app for each environment that it runs on. Basically we have a complex set of properties files that get packaged with each build. For example, database connection strings, server ports, etc are all 'compiled' and packed with the build for the target environment. How do you handle these properties/configurations for your builds?

Comment: Apologies I shouldn't have had the quotes around 'test'. I have edited my answer.

Ah I see. For some reason I thought you were actually compiling on your production machines. In the past I have done as you do. These days I prefer to build a single deployable for all environments and manage environment specific properties externally. It all depends what works best for you :)

Comment: That worked! Regarding environment properties, you say that you manage your properties externally. How do you manage doing variable replacement for you builds? Do you just pass these properties in to your build and then do replacements through your processResources task?

Comment: Glad it worked. No, I don't need to do variable replacement. I don't package environment specific configuration into the built artifact. That way I can build once and deploy the result to ANY environment including production. For example I might read environment config from a file called 'environment.config' on the classpath. The contents of that file vary in each environment, but the compiled/built artifact is exactly the same.

Comment: In my case bootRepackage fails because assemble depends on it. It just happens that :data-layer:bootRepackage does not exist because :data-layer is a shared project. Using the technique suggested in the response is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can skip tasks via the command line with the -x option:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug -x taskToSkip
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible to remove such a dependency. 
You can however *skip the execution of tasks*, eg: skipping all test tasks (in production) goes like this.

```
tasks.withType(Test).each { task ->
    task.enabled = !env.equals('prod')
}
```