# Running Gradle Build From Eclipse without test

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a gradle build file that uses the java plugin. If I want to invoke build from the command line and avoiding running unit tests I can just do this:

```
gradle build -x test
```

However, we'll be calling gradle tasks from Eclipse. Do I need to build a special task for this kind of build? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: do you want to build without test?

Comment: Yes, in our team environment there will be several tests that will break during the development cycle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under `Eclipse > Menu bar "Windows" > Preferences >` left hand side: `Gradle> Arguments > Program Arguments >` put `-x test`

and

Under `Eclipse > Menu bar "Windows" > Preferences >` left hand side: `Gradle EnIDE>` check box the box next to `-x test (--exclude-task test) or use gradle assemble` line.

See if that helps. Make sure GRADLE_HOME is set / known to Eclipse.

[image]

UPDATE:
THIS will stop running test task from any project (as it's global).
If you just want to run `gradle clean build -x test` or similar (once in a while and only on some project), then do something like this:

1. In GRADLE_HOME/init.d folder, create a global common file called `shenzi.gradle`
2. In this common file, add the following:

   ```
   allprojects{
       apply plugin: 'java'
       apply plugin: 'groovy'

       // blah blah uncomment if you need.
       //apply plugin: 'pmd'
       //apply plugin: 'findbugs'
       //apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
       //apply plugin: 'jacoco'

       tasks.withType(Compile) {
           options.debug = true
           options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
       }

       // ..
       // .. more code exists here for commented out lines as shown above, so ignore this in your version
       // .. 

       task myAliasNoTestBuild() << { 
           // see link below on how to create alias tasks
       }
   }
   ```

**OR**

try this solution: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@gradle.codehaus.org/msg09173.html

**OR**

[How to prevent gradle build from executing test task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409660/how-to-prevent-gradle-build-from-executing-test-task)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is that it excludes test from every task. For example, I can't even run the "test" task itself using this fix.

Comment: I tried in Eclipse Neon and there should be no space between -x and test for this to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can locally set this in eclipse

Right Click on **build.gradle --> Run As --> Gradle build -->** This will open a window.

```
Gradle task as :build
Program args as -x test
```

Refer below Image.. All set .. Run Now..

[image]